# Google Identity Platform OAuth server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-identity

I want to user Google Identity Platform as the CIAM solution for our GKE-based cloud service.  We have a requirement to allow 3rd parties to access our cloud APIs using credentials they obtain via OAuth.

For example, our cloud service provides APIs that Google Assistant or Amazon Alexa can access on behalf of our users.  Therefore, we want to provide an OAuth-based token manager that uses the identities of our customers as defined in the Google Identity Platform.

Is this type of OAuth service possible using Google Identity Platform, or the underlying Firebase service that drives it?

Comment: Are the users using google accounts?

Comment: @MabelA. - having a google account is not a requirement.  we want to let users create accounts with our platform directly.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the documentation for [Google Assistant](https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/oauth2), you will need to implement your own OAuth2 endpoints. In the authorization code flow, you need two endpoints:

1. The **authentication endpoint** needs to sign in the user and get their permission to allow the third party (eg. Google) to call the customer's API on their behalf. If the user gives permission then they return an authorization code - which could be implemented by [creating a custom token](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/create-custom-tokens) with Cloud Identity Platform.
2. **Token exchange endpoint** is also needed, which has two functions. The first is to [exchange the authorization code](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/use-rest-api#section-verify-custom-token) created by the first endpoint for a refresh token and an ID token. The second is to [exchange a refresh token](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/use-rest-api#section-refresh-token) for a new ID token. Both of these functions can be delegated to Cloud Identity Platform.

Additional note:

I would suggest to use [custom claims](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/how-to-configure-custom-claims) to ensure that these tokens can only be used for the intended purposes, ie. to perform actions which the Google Assistant needs to do. Users shouldn't be allowed to perform other actions, eg. changing the user's password or providing authorization codes to other third parties.

Also make sure that this endpoint can't be used by malicious third parties. For example, you can check that the redirect URL provided matches what is expected, since this is where the authorization code will be sent to.